# How to silence warning from import IPython.nbformat: "UserWarning: nbformat.current is deprecated."

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I'm working with the example code for importing an IPython (Jupyter) notebook,
[Importing Notebooks](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/4.x/examples/Notebook/rstversions/Importing%20Notebooks.html).  The example code still runs fine, however it generates a warning that I would like to understand and fix:

```
site-packages/nbformat/current.py:15: UserWarning: nbformat.current is deprecated.

- use nbformat for read/write/validate public API
- use nbformat.vX directly to composing notebooks of a particular version

  warnings.warn("""nbformat.current is deprecated.
```

This warning has been discussed since 2015, at least, and yet I cannot find any constructive advice about what to do about it. Is this a warning that can be addressed by fixing code, or is it a function that will disappear from IPython without a replacement?

If you follow the link to the IPython blog, they claim that there is a newer version, but their link points to a non-existent page.

This code example is widely discussed in other threads in Stack Overflow, for example

[python access functions in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29806313/python-access-functions-in-ipython-notebook#comment118069737_29806313)

Comment: The link points to a non-existent page because v5.7.6 docs don't contain the examples section you point to - your link is for 4.x, it's quite old. IIUC this is the page you are looking for: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/5.7.6/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'll study the change from 4.x to 5.7.6, and report back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind the example you've linked up is for a much older version of Jupyter - 4.x. The page with these examples has been relocated at some point, and for the 5.7.6 version of Jupyter (the most recent as of writing this) it's located [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/5.7.6/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html).

First, replace the `from IPython.nbformat import current` import with ​`from nbformat import read`

Then, replace this part of the [4.x snippet](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/4.x/examples/Notebook/rstversions/Importing%20Notebooks.html#notebook-loader):

```
        with io.open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            nb = current.read(f, 'json')
```

with the [newer version](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/5.7.6/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html#Notebook-Loader):

```
        with io.open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            nb = read(f, 4)
```