# Does there exist empty class in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Does there exist special class in python to create empty objects? I tried object(), but it didn't allow me to add fields.
I want to use it like this:

```
obj = EmptyObject()
obj.foo = 'far'
obj.bar = 'boo'
```

Should I each time(in several independent scripts) define new class like this?

```
class EmptyObject:
    pass
```

I use python2.7

Comment: It's two lines of fairly self-evident code, I see no problem with repeating it. Even if you had to add a new `import` to obtain an existing `EmptyObject`, the net savings would be minor.

Comment: You could even put it on one line, no?

Comment: Have you considered [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)? I have a sense you're reinventing a wheel.

Comment: @kojiro What if OP wants to be able to add attributes dynamically, a la JavaScript objects?

Comment: @2rs2ts so, like [Bunch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2597440/418413). Which, personally, I think is a great way to generate problems.

Comment: Have you looked into using an attrdict. There are many implementations of it out there.

Comment: When appropriate, I use `class Struct: pass` because the name 'Struct' reflects how I am using the instances.

Answer (score 10):

[`types.SimpleNamespace`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) was introduced with Python 3.3 to serve this exact purpose. The documentation also shows a simple way to implement it yourself in Python, so you can add it to your pre-Python 3.3 setup and use it as if it was there (note that the actual implementation is done in C):

```
class SimpleNamespace (object):
    def __init__ (self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    def __repr__ (self):
        keys = sorted(self.__dict__)
        items = ("{}={!r}".format(k, self.__dict__[k]) for k in keys)
        return "{}({})".format(type(self).__name__, ", ".join(items))
    def __eq__ (self, other):
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
```

But of course, if you don’t need its few features, a simple `class Empty: pass` does just the same.

Comment: Unfortunately as I've said I use python2.7

Comment: @maggot092 And as I have said, you can easily add the implementation to your Python 2 project and use it as if it was there…

Comment: In this case as you have also said I don't see advantage comparing defining Emty class

Comment: Well, the big advantage would be using a type that does exist in a future Python version, so using an equivalent type will definitely make your intention clear.

Comment: The OP was concerned about having to repeat the trivial two lines in each script. Repeating these 9 lines in every script instead appears like a cure that is worse than the disease.

Comment: @user4815162342 Type definitions can—and should—easily be moved into separate modules, especially when you access the type multiple times from different locations.

Comment: The separate module is a new dependency, which makes it harder, not easier, to distribute the script to a different machine. It can be done, but it's a tradeoff. In the context of the question which asks how to avoid the two-line creation of empty container class, creating a separate module for those two lines is evidently overkill.

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for a place holder object to which you can add arbitrary static members, then the closest I got is an empty lambda function.

```
obj = lambda: None    # Dummy function
obj.foo = 'far'
obj.bar = 'boo'

print obj.foo, obj.bar
# far boo
```

**Remember:** `obj` is *not* an object of a class, *object* doesn't mean *class instance*, because in Python classes and functions are objects at runtime just like class instances

Comment: Why the argument? You could just as well use `lambda: 0`. I'd not use it still though, as this makes it hard to figure out why you'd create the `lambda` in the first place.

Comment: Mhh... While this is certainly interesting, I sure as hell wouldn't want to see this in production code.

Comment: My upvote for originality, but I agree with Lukas Graf, this solution is not for production

Answer (score 7):

There is no `types.SimpleNamespace` in Python 2.7, you could use `collections.namedtuple()` for immutable objects instead:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> FooBar = namedtuple('FooBar', 'foo bar')
>>> FooBar('bar', 'foo')
FooBar(foo='bar', bar='foo')
```

Or `argparse.Namespace`:

```
>>> from argparse import Namespace
>>> o = Namespace(foo='bar')
>>> o.bar = 'foo'
>>> o
Namespace(bar='foo', foo='bar')
```

See also, [How can I create an object and add attributes to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2827623/4279)

Comment: Cool - another reason to use argparse!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new type dynamically with the fields you want it to have using the `type` function, like this:

```
x = type('empty', (object,), {'foo': 'bar'})
x.bar = 3
print(x.foo)
```

This is not entirely what you want though, since it will have a custom type, not an empty type.

Comment: Also, it will create a new type on every invocation, which is fairly expensive.