# Can I convert a namespace object from mutable to immutable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I receive a namespace object from command line arguments.
And I don't want to modify it.
Can I do that or do you have some ideas?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import argparse

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This script is ...')
    parser.add_argument('--confdir', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--outdir', type=str, required=True)
    return parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mutable_namespace = parse_args()

    # I want to prevent overwrite like that.
    mutable_namespace.confdir = "xxx"
```

Comment: *Lock a variable in Python?*

Comment: Just... don't modify it? There's nothing like `const` in Python. The usual philosophy is that if you don't want something done, you just don't do it. It's why we don't have `private`, either.

Comment: Thank you for the adivice. I see, my idea is not appropriate in Python. I understood very well. I'll change the way. Thank you very much.

Comment: related: [How to make an immutable object in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4828080/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I initially proposed the custom Namespace class, but I like this idea of copying `args` to a NamedTuple better.

### Namedtuple

Another option is to copy the values from `args` to an immutable object/class.  A named tuple might do the job nicely.

Create a namespace

```
In [1157]: dest=['x','y']
In [1158]: args=argparse.Namespace()
In [1159]: for name in dest:
   ......:     setattr(args, name, 23)
   ......:     
In [1160]: args
Out[1160]: Namespace(x=23, y=23)
```

now define a namedtuple

```
In [1161]: from collections import namedtuple
In [1163]: Foo = namedtuple('Foo',dest)
```

You could also get the tuple names from the Namespace itself (after parsing)

```
Foo = namedtuple('Foo',vars(args).keys())
```

create such a tuple with values from `args`:

```
In [1165]: foo=Foo(**vars(args))
In [1166]: foo
Out[1166]: Foo(x=23, y=23)
In [1167]: foo.x
Out[1167]: 23
```

and it is immutable:

```
In [1168]: foo.x=34
... 
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Such a namedtuple cannot be used as a Namespace, since `setattr(foo,'x',34)` produces the same error.

A clean way to do all of this is to wrap it all in a function:

```
def do_parse():
   parser = ....
   Foo = namedtuple(...)
   args = parser.parse_args()
   foo = Foo(**vars(args))
   return foo
```

The calling code never sees the mutable `args`, just the immutable `foo`.

### Custom Namespace class

To build on `Ingaz` answer, `argparse` can use your own `Namespace` class.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-namespace-object

```
class MyNamespace(argparse.Namespace):
    pass
    <customize one or more methods>

anamespace = MyNamespace()
args = parser.parse_args(namespace=anamespace)
```

Now `args` and `anamespace` reference the same `MyNamespace` object.  As long as `getattr(anamespace, adest)` and `setattr(anamespace, adest, avalue)` work, `argparse` can use this namespace object.

Now, can you allow `setattr(anamespace, 'string', 'value')`, but disallow `anamespace.string = value`?  I think you can, but it will require a good understanding of how the latter expression works.  It may just require customizing `.__setattr__`, but I haven't studied this aspect of Python in a while.

By design it is possible, and even acceptable to 'monkey patch' the `argparse` namespace - with a custom class like this.

Comment: As long as you're going to all this trouble, you may as well subclass `argparse.ArgumentParser` to wrap its `parse_args` to do the rewrap as an immutable namespace; easier to do that and make your work reusable trivially (users only change the initialization line for the parser and otherwise use it like normal) than to make special `do_parse` for each use case.

Comment: It depends on whether you need to do this kind of thing repeatedly, or just once or twice.  Subclass `ArgumentParser` if you need to reuse some new feature repeatedly.  You can still wrap the parser definition/use in a function to cleanly separate parsing from use.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I understood there's nothing like 'const' and my way is not appropriate in  Python. This is the way in another languages, I think.
I'll follow the Python's way.
Thank you for your answer, I learned a lot.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: a more reusable solution is to create a function that converts a [Bunch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2597440/4279)-like object [such as `argparse.Namespace()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22526544/4279) into a named tuple (it should be straightforward, to create a shallow, non-recursive version).

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine `__setattr__` in your mutable_namespace:

```
class NotMutableException(Exception):pass

class SomeObject(object):
    def init(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 20

some_obj = SomeObject()
some_obj.z = 30

def not_setattr(self, name, value):
    raise NotMutableException

type(some_obj).__setattr__ = not_setattr

some_obj.a = 1000
```

Comment: If you do this to `argparse`'s `Namespace`, you just broke `argparse` for anything else in the code that might use it in the future. Thought I'd give you a heads up. Monkeypatching core classes to disable them is a _big_ no no.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: OP idea is strange from the beginning. So it have equally strange answers.

Comment: It's not that outlandish of an idea.  You can define your own `namespace` class.  As long as the parser is allowed to fetch and set attributes with `getattr` and `setattr`, it should work.