# Create namedtuple from Namspace?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse, namedtuple

How do I initialize a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) from a [`Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace)?

```
import collections
import argparse

nt=collections.namedtuple("nt",["foo","bar"]) # _NOT_ "baz"!
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo')
parser.add_argument('--bar')
parser.add_argument('--baz')
args = parser.parse_args(...)
```

**What do I do if only *some* script arguments go into the namedtuple?**

Here is what I came up with:

```
nt_param=nt(**{f:getattr(args,f,None) for f in nt._fields})
```

is there a more pythonic approach?

Comment: "If all arguments of the program were in nt, I could have passed namespace=nt() to parser.parse_args()." except you couldn't because namedtuples are **immutable**

Comment: @AnthonySottile: thanks, removed.

Comment: A small improvement is to remove the `None` in your call to `getattr`. Since the `Namespace` object already sets any undefined command-line arguments to `None`, you don't have to explicitly return `None` yourself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348568/can-i-convert-a-namespace-object-from-mutable-to-immutable - asks about converting a namespace to immutable.  Besides copying to a `namedtuple` I suggest a custom `Namespace` class.  I also discuss `namedtuple` in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279063/python-typehints-for-argparse-namespace-objects

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/recordtype is a mutable alternative to `namedtype`.

Comment: So the problem comes down to creating a `namedtuple` from a dictionary with a partial overlap in keys.  You not only have to select the keys that match, but define default values for missing ones.  You could use `parser.set_defaults` to handle the missing keys issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the actual type of the namedtuple, you can create an "anonymous" namedtuple representing your `Namespace`.

Here's an approach I've used before:

```
def auto_namedtuple(classname='auto_namedtuple', **kwargs):
    return collections.namedtuple(classname, tuple(kwargs))(**kwargs)
```

Usage in your case:

```
nt = auto_namedtuple(**vars(args))
```

Comment: It is important that the `namedtuple` contains only the specific fields.

Comment: What you're doing seems fine, are you have a specific *problem*?

Comment: Not really, I am just trying to see if I am doing something stupid. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note that while `_fields` has a leading underscore, it is not actually a "private" attribute, the stdlib does this [to avoid conflicting with user namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields)