# Iteratively convert dictionary into set of global variables

Tags: python, global-variables, global

I would like to **iteratively** convert a dictionary into matching global variables like shown below:

```
# starting dictionary
parameters = {
    'a': 3,
    'b': 4
}

# result
a = 3
b = 4
```

now I know quite well the caveats associated with global variables: this is not meant to be a "production" solution but rather a way to use the considerable existing code base for optimization purposes without implementing a heavy restructuring.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# starting dictionary
parameters = {
    'a': 3,
    'b': 4
}

locals().update(parameters)
print(a)
print(b)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
3
4
```

**OR**

```
a, b = parameters['a'], parameters['b']
```

**OR**

[Consider the `Bunch` alternative:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597278/python-load-variables-in-a-dict-into-namespace):

```
class Bunch(object):
    def __init__(self, parameters):
        self.__dict__.update(parameters)

parameters = {
    'a': 3,
    'b': 4
}
vars = Bunch(parameters)
print(vars.a, vars.b)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
3 4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use locals:

```
locals().update({'test': 2})
```

Results:

```
>>test
>>2
```