# Argparse Dictionary to Namespace

Tags: python, argparse

I use `argparse` as an argument parser in my python code. What is the best way to parse a dictionary to an argparse object?

For example, My dictionary is:

```py
{
    "activation_dropout": 0.0,
    "activation_fn": "gelu",
    "attention_dropout": 0.0,
    "beam": 1,
}
```

What I expect is an `argparse.Namespace` object with attributes `activation_dropout`, `activation_fn`, `attention_dropout`, and `beam`

I wish there was a method in `argparse` that takes input as a dictionary and gives out an `argparse` with the namespace as those variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: load variables in a dict into namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597278/python-load-variables-in-a-dict-into-namespace)

Comment: @Tomerikoo, an `argparse.Namespace` isn't a module's `namespace`

Comment: @hpaulj don't know about that, but the second answer there is identical to yours and the accepted gives an alternative way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `**` unpacking:

```
In [57]: adict={'foo':1, 'bar':'astring', 'baz':[1,2,3]}
In [59]: argparse.Namespace(**adict)
Out[59]: Namespace(bar='astring', baz=[1, 2, 3], foo=1)
In [60]: args = argparse.Namespace(**adict)
In [61]: args
Out[61]: Namespace(bar='astring', baz=[1, 2, 3], foo=1)
In [62]: args.bar
Out[62]: 'astring'
```

Its docs:

```
In [63]: argparse.Namespace?
Init signature: argparse.Namespace(**kwargs)
Docstring:     
Simple object for storing attributes.

Implements equality by attribute names and values, and provides a simple string representation.
```

It's a simple object subclass that assigns its `**kwargs` to its attributes.  And provides a basic display method.

`vars` is the standard Python method of reversing that:

```
In [65]: vars(args)
Out[65]: {'foo': 1, 'bar': 'astring', 'baz': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Internally, `parser.parse_args` creates an `argparse.Namespace()` and assigns values with `setattr(args, dest, value)`.